# Large LED Array powered via USB

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, usb-device

I am working on building a keyboard at the moment and I have run into an issue.

I need to power 79 led backlights on the keyboard but I have no idea how to do this given that the power is coming via usb.  I know usb 3 can handle up to 900ma but I want to make this work on all usb.  So I am limited in the assumption that I have 500ma to work with and 5v.

That's 500ma to power two teensy 2.0 ++ and the 79 backlights plus 3 indicator leds.

I cannot find any through-hole leds that are less than roughly 3v and 20ma.  So connecting all the leds in series is pretty much out of the question and since they are 3v I cannot put them in parallel either.

How are commercially made keyboards powering their leds, and they usually have 100+?? How can I power all of these?

Comment: You want to enforce touch-typing by blinding anyone who looks at the keyboard?  79 LEDS at full power will produce lots of light!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEDs will produce light well below 20 mA. The backlight of our display uses a LED with around 1 mA current - you can't see it in daylight but when it's dark it's fine.

You have around 5 mA per LED, that should be plenty (no idea what a teensy is and how much current it needs). Modern LEDs are almost blinding at 20 mA. However I'm not sure if you will find modern and efficient LEDs in through hole, so I'd use SMD LEDs.

Comment: Is the best way to limit how much amperage draw there is with a current limiting resistor?

Comment: Also...teensy - https://www.pjrc.com/teensy

Comment: If you don't plan something special (like RGB settable background lighting), at these power levels I'd say a simple current limiting resistor is good enough. A more efficient way is using a switch mode LED driver, but given the question you ask, that might turn into more trouble that it is worth it.